# Keycode wrong character in onKeyDown

Tags: android, android-studio

When I get an email address like abc@def.com in the event onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) returns me abC2def.com. With this code

```
message +=(char)event.getUnicodeChar();
```

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you are using `getUnicodeChar()` and not `getUnicodeChar(0)` ?

Comment: Yes I copied and pasted the code

Comment: Is this on a device or in the emulator? This doesn't look like anything you've done wrong. It looks more like a bug. It looks like the shift meta character is going in with the 'c' character, rather than the '2' key to get '@'. I think I'd drop in some logging to verify this with event.isShiftPressed() and event.getKeyCode(). I'm assuming that everything looks correct in the GUI, but message is where the characters are messed up.